# SQL Server : skip update if variable is NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a SQL Server database. I want to update the values of an `ID` only if the value is null, if there is a value it should be skipped -> not updated.

I don't know how to realise this "if else" in SQL Server - could somebody give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

This is my pseudo code:

```
UPDATE dbo.mytable
IF FIELD1 IS NOT NULL SKIP --Don't update
ELSE IF FIELD1 IS NULL 
    SET FIELD1 (SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1 
                FROM mytable 
                WHERE {Some ID} = '123' 
                  AND FIELD1 IS NOT NULL) 

WHERE {Some ID} = '123'
AND FIELD1 IS NULL
```

Comment: What value do you want to set it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.FIELD1 = ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 FIELD1 
                     FROM mytable t2
                     WHERE SomeID = '123' 
                     AND FIELD1 IS NOT NULL )
FROM dbo.mytable t
WHERE FIELD1 IS NULL 
  AND SomeId = '123'
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactlly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.mytable
    SET FIELD1 = ?
    WHERE FIELD1 IS NULL;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the value you want to set it to.

If you want to set the value to the "123" value:

```
UPDATE dbo.mytable
    SET FIELD1 = (SELECT t2.FIELD1 FROM dbo.mytable t2 WHERE t2.ID = 123)
    WHERE FIELD1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the below query

```
 UPDATE dbo.mytable
 SET ID = 123
 WHERE ID IS NULL
```

Hope this will help you. It will only update the ID when the value in ID field is NULL.

Comment: Not quite what OP is looking for...ID is presumably a PK and will likely never be null.

Comment: I respect your comment but the user has not given his requirement properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.mytable
    SET FIELD1 = (SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1 
                 FROM mytable 
                 WHERE {Some ID} = '123' 
                 AND FIELD1 IS NOT NULL) 
WHERE {Some ID} = '123'
AND FIELD1 IS NULL --here your IF condition will get filter [[IF FIELD1 IS NOT NULL SKIP --Don't update]]
```